# Android JNI: "Attempt to use stale local reference" error when trying to call a java method from a signal handler

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, signals

I am trying to handle native signlas in JNI code, so I could "Catch" them, and throw a java exception, instead of letting the signals crash my procces.

I install the signal handler, which is being called.
In the signal handler, I am trying to throw a java exception, but get the following error:

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1
```

I have tested the actual throw method call, and it works from outside the signal handler.

in the JNI_onLoad I save the JavaVM pointer like so:

```
static JavaVM *sVm;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved)
{
  sVm = jvm;
  ...install signal handler
}
```

Here is the code in the signal handler:

```
void android_sigaction(int signal, siginfo_t *info, void *reserved)
{
  JNIEnv *env;
  // Get JniEnv from the static JavaVM saved in JNI_OnLoad
  (*sVm)->GetEnv(sVm, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
  jclass cls = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Error"));
  (*env)->ThrowNew(env, cls, NULL);
};
```

also tried getting JniEnv using `AttachCurrentThread` instead, but does not work too:.

```
  jint rs = (*sVm)->AttachCurrentThread(sVm, &env, NULL);
  jclass cls = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Error"));
   if (rs == JNI_OK) {
      (*env)->ThrowNew(env, cls, NULL);
  }
```

Comment: garbage collector is removing the reference of your variables

Comment: @maven to which variable? the only one I use is 'cls' which I declare as Global. no?